# Decrypt GPG file without private key

Tags: unix, encryption, gpgpu, public-key-encryption

I have GPG files encrypted with 2048 bit public/private key, but I have a big problem, i lost the keys.
I know the decryption chances are very low :( .

Is there a "brute force" tool to decrypt GPG files? I will leave the tool running for days to try luck.

```
gpg: encrypted with RSA key, ID E81B3FBCA9713B30
gpg: decryption failed: No secret key
# off=0 ctb=85 tag=1 hlen=3 plen=268
:pubkey enc packet: version 3, algo 1, keyid E81B3FBCA9713B30
        data: [2048 bits]
# off=271 ctb=d2 tag=18 hlen=2 plen=0 partial new-ctb
:encrypted data packet:
        length: unknown
        mdc_method: 2
```

Thanks,

Comment: If [this is result](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2103.06159.pdf) is correct (not peer reviewed), you will need *"177 days with a processor made with 13 436 physical qubits and a multimode memory with 2 hours storage time"*. Probably not achievable just yet. And of course: https://twitter.com/sejaques/status/1371859383949402114

Answer (score 6):

No. Your data is lost.

You are wanting to bruteforce 2^2048 combinations, which is impossible currently.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
Yes, it is almost impossible.